# How to Handle networkonmainthreadexception in Android?

Tags: android

I have following 2 class

```
class CallNetworkMethod extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if (TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)) {
            sendTweet();
        } else {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TwPrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("tweet_msg",getTweetMsg());
            startActivity(i);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //updateLoginStatus();
        loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));
    }

}
```

====================================================

```
public class TwitterUtils {

static ArrayList<String> friens=null;

public static boolean isAuthenticated(SharedPreferences prefs) {

    String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TwConstants.CONSUMER_KEY, TwConstants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);


    try {



        **twitter.getAccountSettings();**

        return true;
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

I got the exception when running this code(networkonmainthreadexception).I debug this code and found the location where exception come out. It is **twitter.getAccountSettings();**  .I think this method should run inside a AsynTask but i dont know how to do that.

Comment: have you tried after removing ` loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));` line ?

Comment: no I need to execute that line.i know that is the point

Comment: i'm not saying you remove that line permanently try i want to known where is issue

Comment: `loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));` this line cause exception. remove `TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)` from it.

Comment: your correct issue is in isAuthenticated(pref) method

Comment: You don't 'handle' it, you fix the coding bug that causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are calling `TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)` in `onPostExecute` because onPostExecute always execute on UI thread then you are getting `networkonmainthreadexception` exception .

to avoid this issue use a `Boolean Flag` to get return from doInBackground and show it in `TextView` in onPostExecute as:

```
class CallNetworkMethod extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
  public static boolean status=false;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

       status=TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //updateLoginStatus();
        loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + status);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you're using the `AsyncTask` wrong.
The idea for the `onBackground` returning a value and the `onPostExecute` receiving a result is to pass to the UI thread something that was done on the background thread.

Something like that:

change the `class CallNetworkMethod extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` to

```
class CallNetworkMethod extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
```

change the `protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {` to

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

   Boolean result = TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs);
        if (result) {
        sendTweet();
    } else {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TwPrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("tweet_msg",getTweetMsg());
        startActivity(i);
    }
    return result;       
}
```

and change the `protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {` to

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + result.toString());
}
```

Comment: Can we change the return type of protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) as Boolean? i cant do this. show error

Comment: I forgot the class signature, see my edit: `class CallNetworkMethod extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>`

Answer (score 0):

```
Note that this method blocks waiting for a network response, so do not call it in a UI thread.
```

This is what is suggested when using:

```
facebook.request("me");
```

Same might be the case with:

```
twitter.getAccountSettings();
```

So, just like other Network connections, which you call using AsyncTasks, call this in some AsyncTask.

Okay, the Error might be here:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //updateLoginStatus();
        loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));
    }
```

You are calling `TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)` in `onPostExecute();`

Comment: He is calling it from an asynctask.

Comment: @RaghavSood Yeah. But he is also calling it in the `onPostExecute();`

Answer (score 0):

Your first call to isAuthenticated() is correctly placed in the AsyncTask. However, when you use:

```
loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));
```

in your onPostExecute(), you're calling a networking method on the UI thread again, as onPostExecute() is run on the UI thread.

Remove this line, or store the result locally from `doInBackground()` and use it here.